# Who was the first ape in science fiction?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre

From *[Planet of the Apes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063442/)* to [Gorilla Grodd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorilla_Grodd) to *[Curious George and the Rocket](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019WV2S8O)* to [Joop the Orangutan](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Joop), apes have a long and varied history in science fiction.

But which was the first ape to appear in a science fiction work? To avoid confusion, I'm limiting apes to the currently living species of gibbons, orangutans, gorillas, chimpanzees and bonobos. **Humans do not count.**

For "science fiction", any work that's on-topic (as science fiction)  on this site should work as an answer.

Preferably, I'd like the first appearance of an ape and the first ape to play a major role.

Comment: If anyone's wondering, I'm considering George an ape, as he has no tail.

Comment: Re: Curious George, I'd say that for biologists monkey vs. ape is really a matter of evolutionary relationships, a monkey that loses its tail like the [barbary macaque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbary_macaque) is still a monkey, likewise if an ape were to re-evolve a tail it would still be an ape.

Comment: @user14111 The question is limited to those apes in particular, yes, but in the opening paragraph, I was talking about all apes. I don't know what species George is. I consider him an ape, but feel free to consider him whatever you want.

Comment: Why the hell do we have an [tag:ape] tag?

Comment: @DrRDizzle Actually it's an [tag:apes] tag </pedant>

Answer (score 5):

I think the boundary between science fiction and non-SF gets a bit fuzzy in early works, but the Science Fiction Encyclopedia entry ["Apes as Human"](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/apes_as_human) lists this 1817 story featuring an orangutan:

> *Melincourt, or Sir Oran Haut-ton* (1817) by Thomas Love Peacock, where Oran Haut-ton saves a young maiden from rape, enters Parliament, and gazes wisely upon the human spectacle.

The full text is available [here](http://archive.org/details/melincourtorsiro00peacuoft), but short of reading it, there's a summary [here](http://www.thomaslovepeacock.net/essays/byronsbear.html) indicating that although the orangutan cannot speak, he shows signs of intelligence:

> Despite his inability to speak, Sir Oran has learned to play the flute and the French horn and to imitate the manners of a polished gentleman. He finds himself completely at home in London society, especially at the opera, and his whole deportment is characterized by an air of high fashion. His prodigious strength and innate chivalry make him an ideal rescuer of damsels in distress. In fact he is the perfection of the "strong, silent type." When the heroine Anthelia is trapped on insular rock in the midst of a raging torrent, Sir Oran calmly sizes up the situation, then proceeds to uproot a large pine in order to bridge the chasm and carry her to safety. He foils one attempt to abduct Anthelia, and at a second attempt has succeeded he is instrumental in rescuing her from the wicked Lord Anophel Achthar, who has threatened to rape her if she will not marry him. Throughout the book he displays a strong sense of natural justice, along with various other attributes of the Noble Savage

This story was satirical and so it's debatable if it should be classified as science fiction, but the entry also mentions another story, published just a bit later in 1824, which it says was *not* intended as satire:

> Charles Pougens's slightly later tale, *Jocko: anecdote détachée des Lettres inédites sur l'instinct des animaux* ["Jocko: Anecdote Extracted from Unpublished Letters on Animal Instinct"] (1824; trans Georges T Dodds as "Jocko" in *The Missing Link and Other Tales of Ape-Men* anth 2010), more directly connects the innocence of the orangutan Jocko to the doctrine of the Noble Savage espoused by Jean-Jacques Rousseau (1712-1778) ... Jocko is not a Satire

The plot description on [p. 75 of *The Apes of Wrath*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Uh_cAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA75) (it looks like chapter 3 of this book, starting on p. 73, would be a good source for early ape tales in general) describes it as

> the story of an orangutan who falls in love with the novel's narrator. Unfortunately for Jocko, the narrator is greedy and forces Jocko to bring him precious stones. Jocko dies and the narrator returns to Europe a rich man.

From this description it's unclear if there are really any elements that could be described as SF, as opposed to just a mildly inaccurate portrayal of orangutan behavior.

Depending on whether you want to include fantasy or only science fiction, [p. 74](http://books.google.com/books?id=Uh_cAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA74) of *The Apes of Wrath* mentions a much earlier candidate:

> in the English *Wagner Book* (1593), an elaboration on the Faust legend, Faust's assistant Wagner is accompanied by an ape assistant, making explicit the traditionally implicit ties between apes and supernatural evil.

Comment: Were the apes given sentience in any science fictiony way?

Comment: Added some info on that, looks like the first was sort of borderline, the second probably not much.

Answer (score 1):

The Hindu epic poem [Ramayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramayana) (written Circa 1100BC) contains a substantial reference to the monkey-king [Hanuman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanuman), a sort of trickster godling. Arguably this text is an early form of Scifi given that it contains [futuristic flying palaces capable of orbital flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimana), possessed of weapons capable of mass destruction.

Hanuman attends the main character as his traveling companion and his speeches, counsel (and kidnapping) form the major part of the plotline for the middle part of the story.

> *He ceased: and Hanuman of all
>
>   The Vánars in the council hall
>
>   In wisdom first, and rank, expressed
>
>   The thoughts that filled his prudent breast:
>
>   '**No marvel thou rememberest yet
>
>   The service thou shouldst ne'er forget,
>
>   How the brave prince of Raghu'a seed
>
>   Thy days from fear and peril freed;
>
>   And Báli for thy sake o'erthrew,
>
>   Whom Indra's self might scarce subdue.***
>
> ...
>
> ***My speech, O King, is free and bold,
>
>   For Ráma, if his anger glow,
>
>   Can, with the terrors of his bow.
>
>   This earth with all the Gods subdue***

Comment: Why do you say the Vimana were capable of "orbital flight", as opposed to just flying magically through the atmosphere?

Comment: I wouldn't really consider a monkey god to be an ape.

Comment: @RogueJedi - He was a monkey who was a god rather than a monkey-god hybrid.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - It could ascend into the heavens. The general interpretation for their use is that they could "*jump into space**" using a mixture of "*fire and water*". In the Ramayana, they went "above the air". That sounds like space-travel to me. They were also multi-media in the sense that they could be used as a submersible.

Comment: Is "jump into space" a direct quote of a translation of some story featuring the Vimana? And if so are you sure the original word that's translated as "space" (or the word translated as 'heavens') clearly means something different than just the air above us?

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I'm no expert, but I'm reasonably sure that people 1100 years ago had no idea that space was vacuum. They thought that the air went all the way up to the planets and the stars. A craft capable of breaching the heavens would simply be a glorified aircraft/balloon. That being said, the fact that it was capable of air travel and underwater travel sounds sci-fi-ish to me. [Submarine planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_submarine) aren't exactly normal even nowadays.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - "Jump into space" is the interpretation of the original text by Swami Dayananda Saraswati. Obviously he's writing from a [modern perspective](http://cgpl.iisc.ernet.in/site/Portals/0/Publications/ReferedJournal/ACriticalStudyOfTheWorkVaimanikaShastra.pdf).

Comment: Sure, they didn't know it was a vacuum, but at the time they probably had a sense there was a significant gap between the height of the clouds and heavenly bodies like stars and planets, so birds couldn't go fly up and sit on one for example. So the question is just whether there are any stories that show the Vimana interacting with such heavenly bodies or whether everything in the stories is compatible with them just flying at the level of the clouds or slightly higher. Also, there's been a whole movement in modern 'fundamentalist' Hinduism to portray the Vedas as portraying a technologically

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I'm quite sure that thinkers in ancient times knew that the air got thinner as you went up (by going up mountains to check) but I don't think they realised that it kept getting thinner until there wasn't any. Hence the Tower of Babel and Icarus' wings.

Comment: (cont.) advanced ancient civilization, Swami Dayananda Saraswati seems to have been this type of fundamentalist so I wouldn't really trust the reliability of his translation, see [this page](http://truthabouthinduism.wordpress.com/2014/05/12/swami-dayananda-saraswati-as-a-hindu-fundamentalist-and-nationalist/).

Comment: @Hypnosifl - What about the fact that it could fly in the air *and* fly underwater. That's pretty nifty.

Comment: I agree with that your comment about not knowing the air disappeared completely, but my point about the sense of a difference in height between clouds and heavenly bodies doesn't depend on whether they thought there was still some air at the height of those bodies. And yes, amphibious flying palaces are nifty!

Comment: Ancient philosophers were well aware that planets and stars were very far away. They even had a stab at guessing how far and although their calculations were [hilariously inaccurate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Sizes_and_Distances), the fact that the moon and the Sun were **very far away indeed** is something that's been known about since at least 1000BC

Comment: Yes, that was my point--that the people telling these stories about Vimana likely did know this, so *given* that I was wondering if there were any stories that suggested that the Vimana reached the height of the stars and planets, or if all their depictions are compatible with them just being around the level of the clouds.